# Sorting pages in a Wagtail PageChooserPanel dialog

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to explicitly order the list of pages based on some attribute (e.g. `page.specific.popularity`) in a Wagtail PageChooserPanel? http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/panels.html does not mention this as possibility, and I can't find anything else in the docs that hints at how one might make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a hook called `construct_page_chooser_queryset` that allows you to modify the `pages` results that get shown in the page chooser modal.

- docs - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#construct-page-chooser-queryset
- Code were used for reference - https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/views/chooser.py
- Note: this will affect the `admin/pages/search` page and ALL page chooser modals, you can read the request object to return different values accordingly (the page chooser modal always comes to the same request)

#### Example Code

This would be in your `wagtal_hooks.py` file, example based on docs linked above.

```py
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('construct_page_chooser_queryset')
def order_pages_in_chooser(pages, request):
    if "choose-page" in request.path:
        # showing page in a page chooser modal
        return pages.order_by('?')  # order randomly

    # search results shown in admin/pages/search - return in default order
    return pages
```